# Xcode and flutter compiler error: reading from wrong directory

Tags: xcode, macos, flutter

I am getting this error and my app will not compile.   The problem is that I had to upgrade macos to be able to compile apps on newer iOS versions, and in doing so I copied my project over from my mojave machine to my catalina one.   The directory users/mojave no longer exists, and it needs to be replaced with users/catalina

I have searched the app for any reference of mojave anywhere, and replaced it all with catalina.   I have rebooted macos, and it still fails, looking for this old directory.

How do I find and change these references?   I am not able to find anything online, possibly because I don't really know how to phrase this question.

[image]

Comment: Is this a complicated question?   I know nothing about macs and xcode, so I assumed this would be very simple for someone that does.  I can provide more information if that would help?   I am not sure what is needed to give you the full picture.

Thanks guys.

Comment: add flutter doctor output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is another one of those occasions where the error doesn't really indicate what is wrong here.

The problem was that "pods setup" had not been run, so it had not initialised.

The reason for this is that when I ran "pod setup" it does literally nothing.

Researching this issue online, it seems an issue since cocoapods 1.8.0, and the dev team said that they had hotfixed this issue and it would be available from version 1.8.1

Well, this was version 1.8.4 and it is still broken with exactly the same issue.

The fix was to uninstall it completely:

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

And then install version 1.7.5:

sudo gemo install cocoapods --version 1.7.5

From here, with the older version installed that actually works, "pod setup" runs fine, pods is initialised and the app no longer looks in the incorrect folders.

Hope this helps someone.